# Vaadin Client-Side application integration with server-side application

Tags: vaadin, client-side, server-side

Is it possible to create an Vaadin server side application which contains Vaadin client side application as a widget ? 
Thanx in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you wish to do. The widgetset IS the client side code

Comment: This question does not make sense to me. Can you expound on your intentions? I wonder if you misunderstand how Vaadin works. Your Vaadin app with its layouts and buttons, labels, fields and such widgets all live in memory *on the server* as Java objects. Those layouts and widgets are rendered remotely in the web browser automatically by Vaadin via standard web technologies (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.). So there is no such thing as a “Vaadin client side application”.

Comment: Vaadin supports two development models: server-side and client-side. Client-side Vaadin code is executed in the web browser as JavaScript code. The code is written in Java, like all Vaadin code, and then compiled to JavaScript .

I am creating an server side application which contains a button on the click of that button I want to change the text of the label , I know there is a method Button.addClickListener() but it send the request to server to change the text which I think is not worth. It can be done using js. I hope u understand my question now

Comment: You could extend the components to handle such cases, but it will not be a simple thing. Much easier to handle this server side

Comment: I am optimizing my application and I am thinking that it will be good if I handle such request at client side only.

Comment: Then use @AndréSchild hint and write your own component based on GWT components.